# Formating output of Haskell permutation

Tags: string, haskell, concatenation

i have this list in my .hs file

```
listofstrings= ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"]
```

and i am calling the file in ghci with

```
load permutations.hs
```

with this command

```
permutations listofstrings
```

i get

```
[["string1","string2","string3","string4"],["string2","string1","string3","string4"],["string3","string2","string1","string4"],["string2","string3","string1","string4"],["string3","string1","string2","string4"],["string1","string3","string2","string4"],["string4","string3","string2","string1"],["string3","string4","string2","string1"],["string3","string2","string4","string1"],["string4","string2","string3","string1"],["string2","string4","string3","string1"],["string2","string3","string4","string1"],["string4","string1","string2","string3"],["string1","string4","string2","string3"],["string1","string2","string4","string3"],["string4","string2","string1","string3"],["string2","string4","string1","string3"],["string2","string1","string4","string3"],["string4","string1","string3","string2"],["string1","string4","string3","string2"],["string1","string3","string4","string2"],["string4","string3","string1","string2"],["string3","string4","string1","string2"],["string3","string1","string4","string2"]]
```

how can i get a list for each combination with linebreak and without comma, " , [], spaces and rest of the signs?

So it should look like this

```
string1string2string3string4
string2string1string3string4
string3string2string1string4
string2string3string1string4
string3string1string2string4
string1string3string2string4
string4string3string2string1
string3string4string2string1
string3string2string4string1
string4string2string3string1
string2string4string3string1
string2string3string4string1
string4string1string2string3
```

Comment: @nicodp Is there any command out there which could give
`string1
string1string2
string1string2string3
string1string2string3string4
string2
string2string1string3string4`

etc. :) ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you can do is to use `map` to get a new list of strings but with new-line characters appended to each line:

```
listsWithNewLines = map (++ ["\n"]) $ permutations listofstrings
```

and then print them out using `mapM_`:

```
mapM_ putStr (concat listsWithNewLines)
```

Why `mapM_`? Because you want to perform an `IO` action that returns nothing `()`, in other words, you want to do some computation inside the `IO` monad.

Let's review the `mapM_`'s type:

```
mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()
```

Our computation will be `putStr`, that has the following type:

```
putStr :: String -> IO ()
```

And as we want a list of strings as the second argument for `mapM_`, we need to flatten our list of strings with new lines like so: `concat listWithNewLines`

Hence, we end up with the following type:

```
(String -> IO ()) -> [String] -> IO ()
```

which is the type of `mapM_`, but with `a = String`, `b = ()` and `m = IO`.

Comment: thank you. and how can i combine several commands?
because you wrote "and then you can", one after another in the "*Main>"?

Comment: The first command gave me that error 
`<interactive>:1:47: error:
    * Couldn't match type Char' with [Char]'
      Expected type: [[[Char]]]
        Actual type: [[Char]]
    * In the second argument of map', namely listofstrings'
      In the expression: map (\ ls -> ls ++ ["\n"]) listofstrings
      In an equation for listsWithNewLines':
          listsWithNewLines = map (\ ls -> ls ++ ["\n"]) listofstrings`

Comment: Edited, instead of `listofstrings` you should use `permutations listofstrings`

Comment: Great nicodp! and how can i write the output to a text file on windows ?

Comment: Could go in this direction?
`import Data.Set
import Data.Maybe
import Text.Printf
import System.IO
import System.Environment
import Data.List

listofstrings = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"]
main = listsWithNewLines <= map (\ls -> ls ++ ["\n"]) (permutations listofstrings)
mapM_ putStr (concat listsWithNewLines)
writeFile :: ./outpu -> mapM_ -> IO ()`

Answer (score 4):

You can join strings of each sublist with `concat`, then you can join lines together with `unlines`:

```
unlines (concat <$> permutations listofstrings)
```

[Here's an example](https://repl.it/repls/RespectfulDarkorchidIrishwaterspaniel)

Comment: Thank you. I tried it https://repl.it/@jonasss/RespectfulDarkorchidIrishwaterspaniel but that does not work. Whats my fault here?

Comment: Your fault is not explaining exactly what doesn't work and how. I can't diagnose a problem if I don't know the symptoms.

Comment: In your example you take already the outpupt of the listofstrings= ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"] from example of the first post. On that listofstrings i want to perform the permutations  command, and the outpupt generated there is nicely formated by your proposal. 
How can i fix it to make the string input generic?
Second, how can i write this to a file?

Comment: I also tried that code `import Data.List

listofstrings= ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"]` in a .hs file, and with ghci i executed `*Main> permutations listofstrings; joined = unlines (concat <$> listofstrings); putStr joined` but that does not work